# PHP Regular Expression to check Alphameric String

Tags: php, regex

I wrote the `PHP` code using `Regular Expression`. I give the following array as input string:

```
$alphmericGoodCases = array('ASDFGH123', 'ASFGH1234', '1234567', '555 abcdf', '#$&%^@-');
foreach($alphmericGoodCases as $alphmericGoodCase){
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\s_-]+$/', $alphmericGoodCase)) {
   echo "true";
}
 else 
   echo "false";
}
```

The output is like as `true`, `true`, `true`, `true` and `false.` But, I want the last one is also `true.` Where I am missing the `Regular Expression`?

Comment: That last string is not alpha numeric. Why would you expect it to be `true`? Ever? If you want those characters to be valid, add them to the regex as a valid character.

Comment: I have to check the special characters.

Comment: That last one is infact a good use case for 'not alphanumeric'

Comment: `Ok`. I will discard it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want the special characters, just use this shorter version:

```
$alphmericGoodCases = array('ASDFGH123', 'ASFGH1234', '1234567', '555 

abcdf', '#$&%^@-');
foreach($alphmericGoodCases as $alphmericGoodCase)
{

   if(preg_match('/^.+$/', $alphmericGoodCase)) {
      echo "true";
   }
   else 
      echo "false";
}
```

This basically says "match any string, except the newline character"